# DBCollection save() equivalent in mongo 3.3

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-java-3.3.0

Our current implementation with `mongo-java-driver:3.0.4` for a document update is as follows -

```
private void updateParam(String param1, String param2) {
    Param param = new Param(param1, param2);
    DBCollection collection = mongoClient.getDB("databaseName").getCollection("collectionName");
    collection.save(new BasicDBObject(param.toMap()));
}
```

where `param.toMap()` is implemented as

```
public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    return JSONObjectMapper.getObjectMapper().convertValue(this, Map.class);
}
```

---

With `mongo-java-driver:3.4.0-rc1` the implementation I tried was using `insertOne` as

```
private void updateParam(String param1, String param2) {
    Param param = new Param(param1, param2);
    MongoCollection<Param> mongoCollection = mongoClient.getDatabase("databaseName").getCollection("collectionName", Param.class);
    mongoCollection.insertOne(param);
}
```

Considering the information from source [DBCollection's save](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#save-com.mongodb.DBObject-)

> - If a document does not exist with the specified '_id' value, the
>     method performs an insert with the specified fields in the document.
> - If a document exists with the specified '_id' value, the method
>     performs an update, replacing all field in the existing record with
>     the fields from the document.

But I doubt the [insertOne](http://api.mongodb.com/java/current/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html#insertOne-TDocument-) implementation now that I am using it for the similar effect as to the `save()` previously.

> Inserts the provided document. If the document is missing an
>   identifier, the driver should generate one

***Question*** - Is there any similar way as of `save()` with current `MongoCollection` approach? Is there a way to use `_id` of `Param` or do something similar without using it as well?

---

***Edit :*** 
Param is defined as  -

```
public class Param {

  private String param2;
  private String param2;

  public Param() {
  }

  public Param(String param1, String param2) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
  }

  public Map<String, Object> toMap() {
    return JSONObjectMapper.getObjectMapper().convertValue(this, Map.class);
  }

}
```

and has a `ParamCodec implements Codec<Param>`  which is registered using `CodecRegistry` as follows to the client :

```
CodecRegistry codecRegistry = CodecRegistries.fromRegistries(MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry(),
            CodecRegistries.fromCodecs(new ParamCodec()));

MongoClientOptions clientOptions = new MongoClientOptions.Builder()
    ....
    .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
    .build();

MongoClient(addresses, clientOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use

```
findOneAndUpdate(Bson filter, Bson update, FindOneAndUpdateOptions options)
```

with FindOneAndUpdateOptions with upsert option set to true.

You can pass the _id as the query filter and param as your update and when the query matches the _id it will upsert the value and if no match is found it will insert a new row.

Comment: What if the `Param` doesn't have a field called `_id`?

Comment: but you will need an identifier field ??? How would Mongo know when to update vs save ? Or you can pass any other criteria which will resolves to a record in the filter and based on that if it is a match update occurs, if not then insert occurs.