# What is the correct method to update a document while using Mongo Cursor?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, mongodb-java-3.3.0

I am trying to update a document in Mongo DB using cursor. My Mongo DB Java driver version is 3.3.0. Following is my code snippet.

```
MongoCollection<Document> collection = mongoDb.getCollection("customer");
MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find().iterator();
try{
    while(cursor.hasNext()){
        Document oldDoc = cursor.next();
        //created new Document newDoc
        collection.replaceOne(oldDoc, newDoc);
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Though this way, I can update the document, **I think this is not the efficient way because here collection is being searched 2 times.** I want to update the old document with some values and later on want to save it using some methods like *collection.update(oldDoc)* or *collection.save(oldDoc)* without creating a new document. I searched and came across the following post.

[Java, MongoDB: How to update every object while iterating a huge collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15969592/java-mongodb-how-to-update-every-object-while-iterating-a-huge-collection)

This is exactly what I want, but I don't find ***save()*** method in the new API. So I have 3 questions here.

1. What is equivalent of ***save()*** method in Mongo DB Java driver 3.3.0 API through which I can update or save a document while iterating a cursor?
2. Is there anyway by which I can update the existing document without creating a new document in Mongo DB Java driver 3.3.0 API?
3. Above link shows ***save()*** was part of Mongo DB Java driver API earlier. Any expert answer, why it got dropped from API?

Comment: Can you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41187740/dbcollection-save-equivalent-in-mongo-3-3) ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the additional search, the `replaceOne` method's first parameter is a filter. Using the old doc as filter will use the _id property of the document which should be relatively fast.
So basically, the way you do it, is correct. But bear in mind that the operation is non-transactional, which means the update may affect the cursor's result set. So it could happen, that the updated document will be stored at a positions the cursor has not yet passed, resulting in the document being processed twice.

Regarding your questions.

1. The semantics of `save` method in mongo shell is to update or insert the document if not yet existing (aka upsert). The closest thing to that on the `MongoCollection` is [`updateOne()`](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.3/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#updateOne-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-com.mongodb.client.model.UpdateOptions-com.mongodb.async.SingleResultCallback-) with an [`UpdateOptions`](https://api.mongodb.com/java/3.3/com/mongodb/client/model/UpdateOptions.html) `upsert` set to true. That's basically what the `save` command does. But  `replaceOne` leads to the same result, if the replacement document is a modified version of the original one.
2. Why worrying about object creation? In java it comes at next to no cost and don't worry about GC or Memory consumption as those shortlived objects are GC'ed pretty fast. If you want to have code more concise you may create a dedicated filter object with just the `_id` of the oldDoc, modify the oldDoc and use it instead of the new Doc.

For example:

```
UpdateOptions upsert = new UpdateOptions().upsert(true);
Bson idFilter = Filters.eq("_id", oldDoc.getObjectId("_id"));
//modify the oldDoc
oldDoc. ...
collection.replaceOne(idFilter, oldDoc, upsert);
```

Comment: What about `findOneAndUpdate()` ?

Comment: both behave the same way when only one document matches the filter. But behave different, when multiple documents match. It also returns the unmodified document, but if the updated document depends on that data, findAndUpdate won't help you. Technically, `findAndUpdate` or `findAndModify` is a command while `save()` is an `insert()` if updated doc has an `_id` or an `update()` with upsert=true if it has no `_id`.

Comment: I still don't understand how `replaceOne` is closer  to `save()`. You can't modify (update) using `replaceOne`. You could have used `update*` which is closer to `save` or `find*Update*` like I mentioned before.

Comment: a lot of those methods have similar and overlapping behavior and subtle differences, depending on the document you pass to replace, the resulting behavior _could_ be the same as with update. To understand the behavior, it sometimes help to look at the implementations, i.e. in shell `db.yourCollection.save` (without parentheses) shows the javascript implementation. `save` is implemented with `insert` and `update`, `findAndModify` is a command, `replaceOne` is a bulk operations. But there is no `save` in the java driver, and the closest function would be update with upsert=true.